How do I threshold a numpy array, where the false condition depends on the number changed?
I am trying to threshold a 2D numpy array, where if the value is greater than a threshold, it is set to 255, else it is set to a value following this equation:
1 + tanh(PHI * (n - THRESHOLD))

where n is the value I am applying the threshold to. I need this method to use vectorization or be equal in performance to a vectorized method.
I tried using list comprehension, but the performance was not up to scratch, I have also tried vectorizing the threshold function, and then applying it, but it turned the array into a garbled mess. I have also tried to use this method (I have forgotten the name):
arr[arr > threshold] = 255
arr[arr <= threshold] = 0

I've also tried numpy's apply_along_axis() function, but both would only let me apply absolute values and not values dependent on the value being thresholded. I would use Python's map() function, but I don't like the casting, and how it becomes awkward to use on 2D arrays.

Showing the list comprehension might help us see what you are doing (with [mcve]).  np.vectorize and np.apply_along_axis aren't speed tools.  What exactly was wrong with the no-name 'masked' case?

arr = threshold * (arr > threshold) + (1 + tanh(PHI * (n - THRESHOLD))) * (arr <= threshold)

I believe you're looking for numpy.where, i.e.:
import numpy as np

np.where(
    arr > threshold, 
    255, 
    1 + np.tanh(PHI * (arr - THRESHOLD))
)

This can be seen as "the numpy way" of doing an if/else, and is equivalent of the following (much slower) code:
out = np.empty_like(arr)
for i in arr.shape[0]:
    for j in arr.shape[1]:
        n = arr[i, j]
        if n > threshold:
            out[i, j] = 255
        else:
            out[i, j] = 1 + np.tanh(PHI * (n - THRESHOLD))


@Onyambu, the OP hasn't told us anything about the range of values in arr.  Or why he's using this THRESHOLD.  It may be because tanh can't be evaluated for some n, but it may be some entirely different reason.  np.tanh like most ufunc takes  where/out parameters to limit calculation points.

@Onyambu, tanh(n) ranges between -1 and 1, for all possible values of n.  So I don't see where np.where would be bad.

Define your main calculation as a function (for convenience):
In [584]: def foo(n, PHI, THRESHOLD):
     ...:     return 1 + np.tanh(PHI * (n - THRESHOLD))
     ...:     

Setup some values:
In [589]: phi = 1; threshold=2; arr = np.linspace(-3,3,13);arr
Out[589]: 
array([-3. , -2.5, -2. , -1.5, -1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,
        2.5,  3. ])

In [590]: cond = arr>threshold

With this function we can calculate values for any number, plus or minus.  result limits of np.tanh are -1,1.  See the comments on the other answer on how other functions might yield some nan and warnings.  None of that with this function.
In [591]: res = foo(arr,phi,threshold); res
Out[591]: 
array([9.07957374e-05, 2.46789152e-04, 6.70700261e-04, 1.82210239e-03,
       4.94524631e-03, 1.33857018e-02, 3.59724199e-02, 9.48517464e-02,
       2.38405844e-01, 5.37882843e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.46211716e+00,
       1.76159416e+00])

To apply your threshold, just assign a new value to a selected number of the res elements (here the last 3):
In [592]: res[cond]=10; res
Out[592]: 
array([9.07957374e-05, 2.46789152e-04, 6.70700261e-04, 1.82210239e-03,
       4.94524631e-03, 1.33857018e-02, 3.59724199e-02, 9.48517464e-02,
       2.38405844e-01, 5.37882843e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01,
       1.00000000e+01])

np.where does essentially the same thing:
In [593]: np.where(cond, 10, foo(arr,phi,threshold))
Out[593]: 
array([9.07957374e-05, 2.46789152e-04, 6.70700261e-04, 1.82210239e-03,
       4.94524631e-03, 1.33857018e-02, 3.59724199e-02, 9.48517464e-02,
       2.38405844e-01, 5.37882843e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01,
       1.00000000e+01])

The cond and ~cond are boolean, but can be used as 0/1 values:
In [594]: (~cond)*foo(arr,phi,threshold)+(cond)*10
Out[594]: 
array([9.07957374e-05, 2.46789152e-04, 6.70700261e-04, 1.82210239e-03,
       4.94524631e-03, 1.33857018e-02, 3.59724199e-02, 9.48517464e-02,
       2.38405844e-01, 5.37882843e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01,
       1.00000000e+01])

A list comprehension version.  For this small example this won't be that much slower, if at all:
In [595]: [10 if n>=2 else foo(n,phi,threshold) for n in arr]
Out[595]: 
[9.079573740489177e-05,
 0.00024678915197251516,
 0.000670700260932966,
 0.0018221023888013166,
 0.004945246313269536,
 0.013385701848569687,
 0.0359724199241831,
 0.0948517463551336,
 0.23840584404423515,
 0.5378828427399902,
 10,             # oops use >- here
 10,
 10]

Another way, is to calculate foo for only the ~cond values.  That would avoid warnings if foo had problematic inputs:
In [596]: res = np.zeros_like(arr)
     ...: res[cond] = 10
     ...: res[~cond] = foo(arr[~cond],phi,threshold)
     ...: res
Out[596]: 
array([9.07957374e-05, 2.46789152e-04, 6.70700261e-04, 1.82210239e-03,
       4.94524631e-03, 1.33857018e-02, 3.59724199e-02, 9.48517464e-02,
       2.38405844e-01, 5.37882843e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01,
       1.00000000e+01])

ufunc like np.tanh take a pair of parameters, where and out that can be used limit which inputs are used, and which are skipped.  tanh doesn't need them, but functions like np.log or np.divide can use them to avoid warnings due to negative or zero inputs.
We could modify the foo to use these parameters:
In [605]: def foo1(n, PHI, THRESHOLD):
     ...:     return 1 + np.tanh(PHI * (n - THRESHOLD), 
              where=~cond, out=9+np.zeros_like(arr))
     ...:     

In [606]: foo1(arr, phi, threshold)
Out[606]: 
array([9.07957374e-05, 2.46789152e-04, 6.70700261e-04, 1.82210239e-03,
       4.94524631e-03, 1.33857018e-02, 3.59724199e-02, 9.48517464e-02,
       2.38405844e-01, 5.37882843e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01,
       1.00000000e+01])

